# In SignalR Core how can i exclude a connection from being notified

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

The scenario is as follow:

I have multiple WPF clients that have a SignalR connection with a server. One WPF client calls a REST API to generate an order. The server would like to notify all WPF clients that an order was placed except for the WPF client that created the order.

Note that the my notification logic is put outside of the hub class.

What is the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a build-in `Hub.Clients.Others` to achieve your requirement.

Here is a sample:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-clients-object

Comment: Thank you for the response, I edited my initial question so that i describe more clearly my scenario. Because my notification logic is outside of the Hub i can not use Others.

Comment: Please share enough code to reproduce your issue. Thanks.